# How can I get to open a combobox on image click, below the image? (In Sencha EXTJS)

Tags: extjs

How can I get to open a combobox on image click, below the image? The image is currently on a panel, and the combobox appears right beside the image. I am using tap function to do so!

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create({
        xtype:'window',
        title:'Your panel',
        width:300,
        height:200,
        layout:{
            type:'hbox'
        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'image',
                src:'https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300',
                width:50,
                height:50,
                listeners:{
                    el: {
                        click: function() {
                            var combo=Ext.getCmp('mycombo');
                            combo.expand();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
            xtype:'combobox',
            id:'mycombo',
            store:['data1','data2']
            }
        ]
    }).show();
```

use combo.expand() to expand the combo, and listeners on el element to add click or tap

Comment: Thank you George. According to this code, the search is already present. But I want the search to come only after clicking the image and also the search should appear below the image.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

```
launch : function() {
    Ext.create({
        xtype:'window',
        title:'Your panel',
        width:300,
        height:200,
        layout:{
            type:'vbox'
        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'image',
                src:'https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300',
                width:50,
                height:50,
                listeners:{
                    el: {
                        click: function() {
                            var combo=Ext.getCmp('mycombo');
                            combo.show();
                            combo.expand();                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
            xtype:'combobox',
            id:'mycombo',
            store:['data1','data2'],
            hidden: true
            }
        ]
    }).show();
}
```

});